# Border Bottom on display inline element

Tags: html, css

I thought this was going to be an easy CSS fix, but I can't seem to find a solution that works in all instances.

I am trying to make the "Some Title That Wraps" text in the fiddle bellow be underlined without the underline going further than the length of text. I have accomplished this if `.title-container` has `width: 200px;`, but now if you change the class `.title-container` to have a `width: 230px;` than I would like the underline to keep going and end where the text "That" ends. Please see image bellow of what I mean.

[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bhde0rsq/31/

Comment: make the element inline-block instead of inline ?

Comment: The underline than extends to far when the `.title-container` element is set to `width: 200px;`

Comment: Tricky one, this!  I was thinking along the lines of using `text-decoration: underline;` and obscuring the top row's underline with `line-height:90%`.  Looks OK for the narrow 200px version but I can't get you a solution to work for the wider `.title-container`, I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

This code will trigger initially to set the width, then whenever the screen changes, the width is ALWAYS equal to the  title width.

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
  set_width(); // Triggers on resize
})

set_width(); // Initial Trigger

function set_width() {
  var title_width = $(".title h1").width();
  $(".my-underline").css("width",title_width + "px");
}
```

```css
.title-container {
  width:200px;
  background: cyan;
}

.title h1 {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

/* hr style */
.my-underline {
  height:5px;
  background-color:black;
  display:table;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title-container">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Some Title That Wraps</h1>
    <span class="my-underline"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am looking for more of a responsive solution. Adding a fixed `width:166px;` to the underlining element wouldn't work in my situation. Sorry.

Comment: Question, will the text always be wrapped like that? If so, we can use Javascript to calculate the width of the object, then assign that width value to the distance.

Comment: Was hoping to stick to CSS, but if this is not possible than ya I'll have to use some JS.

Comment: My approach would be using jquery to detect the titles width, then assign that width to the border whenever it changes. Are you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: That is my personal approach, I can't go deeper but this is as much as I can give.

Comment: Why the down vote? Code perfectly resembles what OP wanted? Explanation for DV?